# Recaptch rendering unclear

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, captcha, recaptcha

I am trying to implement reCaptcha in my project, but I'm stuck in a bit of a problem.

Whenever I browse to a website with reCaptcha from Chrome, I get a weird interface which asks me to fill some (extremely) hard to recognize random letters, and when I eventually get them right, I get some really long code that I should paste into a second input.

Now, if I browse to the same website from say, Internet Explorer, I get this cool checkbox with no letters and everything just works.

Example from Google's URL shortener (Chrome):

[image: Browsing from Chrome]

And same, on Internet Explorer:

[image: Browsing from Internet Explorer]

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: These are both recaptcha (they share the same icon). Recaptcha is deciding which method to use to verify you're not a robot. I don't think there's a way to force this. Google is trying to transition to the newer, single checkbox method. https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Comment: But why is this working differently on the same PC? I'd really prefer to use chrome, an so will the users of my website..

Comment: It reads different cues to decide what form of captcha you get. I've mostly heard about how it processes mouse over events to determine if it's a human holding a mouse or a computer programmatically clicking a mouse. In addition to that metric, it might also use agent string or IP address to help pick a method. That's purely conjecture but it does seem to be a complicated process that recaptcha goes through to decide how to authenticate a user.

Comment: The rendering happens instantly on load, it cant possibly decide what to render based on user interaction events, as there aren't any. Also tried to spoof IE's User Agent in Chrome, and still got the above mentioned weird reCaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you had your reCaptcha automatically rendered instead of explicitly rendering it.

If you want consistency, try to explicitly render the reCaptcha and set the grecaptcha.render parameter 'type' to 'image'

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Explicit render after an onload callback</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var onloadCallback = function() {
      grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
        'sitekey': 'your_site_key',
        'type': 'image'
      });
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="?" method="POST">
    <div id="html_element"></div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found the problem, feel a bit silly now.

After inspecting and comparing the flow of my page load both on Chrome and Internet Explorer using Fiddler, I've noticed some differences which I traced back to this pesky Chrome extension named '[Disconnect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disconnect/jeoacafpbcihiomhlakheieifhpjdfeo)'. Removed it, and solved my problem.

Anyway, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Due to the nature of the solution, this question should probably be deleted. Nice work on figuring it out though - Fiddler to the rescue!